I need help to prove that$\int^1_0 x^{m-1}\ln^2(1-x)dx=\frac{2}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{H_{k}}{k}$
Show that $$\int^1_0 x^{m-1}\ln^2(1-x)dx=\frac{2}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{H_{k}}{k}$$
We know:
$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
and using cauchy product
Therfore:
$$\begin{align*}
\ln^2(1-x)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(n-k+1)}\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k+1}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}H_n
\end{align*}$$
then:
$$\begin{align*}
\int^1_0 x^{m-1}\ln^2(1-x)dx&=2\int^1_0\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+m}}{n+1}H_n\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(n+m+1)(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{2}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)}-\frac{H_n}{(n+m+1)}
\end{align*}$$
How can I follow up on the solution?  Thank you for your attention

You can also find this result in the book “(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series” by Cornel Ioan Vălean.

Let $I_m=\int_0^1 x^{m-1}\ln^2(1-x)\,dx$ for $m\geqslant 0$.
Then, for $m>0$, integrating by parts twice,
\begin{align}
mI_m-(m-1)I_{m-1}
&=-\int_0^1\big(x^{m-1}(1-x)\big)'\ln^2(1-x)\,dx
\\&=-2\int_0^1 x^{m-1}\ln(1-x)\,dx
\\&=\frac2m\int_0^1(1-x^m)'\ln(1-x)\,dx
\\&=\frac2m\int_0^1\frac{1-x^m}{1-x}\,dx
\\&=\color{gray}{\frac2m\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^m x^{k-1}\,dx}=\frac2m H_m.
\end{align}

The result can also be written as $$I_m=\frac{{H_m}^2+H_m^{(2)}}{m},\quad H_m^{(2)}:=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{k^2}$$ (proven directly or using this after $x=1-t$).

OP wants to simplify
$$\frac{2}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)}-\frac{H_n}{(n+m+1)}
=\frac{2}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\tfrac1k}{(n+1)}-\frac{\tfrac1k}{(n+m+1)}$$
By $k=n$ diagonal trick
$$\frac{2}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\tfrac1k\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)}-\frac1{(n+m+1)}
=\frac{2}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\tfrac1k(\tfrac1{k+1}+\tfrac1{k+2}+...+\tfrac1{k+m})
$$
Can you complete by telescoping sums?
